# XSLT 2.0, replace function: How to replace matched group with upper case?

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath, replace, uppercase

If have a following element in my XSL file:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(lower-case(@name), '_([a-z0-9])', '$1')" />
```

For example from 'get_polygene_lubricants' it makes 'getpolygenelubricants'.

What I want to do is to replace the first letter after '_' with
the uppercase variant of the letter. I googled, read documentation,
but I was not able to found any solution in XSLT for that simple
replacement.

Maybe somebody knows whether it is possible in XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the requirements of the problem. I have corrected my answer and now it produces exactly the result you expect. Please, have a look :)

Comment: Sorry, THere is a bug in SO. I couldn't read your latest comment to me. IE crashed and now I don't seethe comment. Could you, please, repeat it?

Comment: @Jagger It is edited and produces your result -- just with a single XPath expression :) Do you read your responses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited**: Per clarification from the original poster, the first string delimited by the underscores should not have its starting letter capitalized.

**This solution does not use recursion and should be quite more efficient**.

**Here is the new solution**:

```
string-join(
            (for  $i in 1 to count(tokenize(.,'_')),
                  $s in tokenize(.,'_')[$i],
                  $fl in substring($s,1,1),
                  $tail in substring($s,2)
               return
                  if($i eq 1)
                   then $s
                   else concat(upper-case($fl), $tail)
             ),
                        ''
           )
```

The result is now exactly as required:

```
underLinedString
```

**Below is the old solution**.

**The replace() function supposes that you have a fixed replacement** -- therefore it is not the best tool for solving this problem.

**Here is a one-liner XPath 2.0 solution** (and it certainly can be used as part of an XSLT 2.0 transformation :)     ):

```
string-join(
            (for $s in tokenize(.,'_'),
                 $fl in substring($s,1,1),
                 $tail in substring($s,2)
               return
                 concat(upper-case($fl), $tail)
             ),
            ''
           )
```

**When we use the above expression in an XSLT 2.0 transformation like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "string-join(
                   (for $s in tokenize(.,'_'),
                    $fl in substring($s,1,1),
                    $tail in substring($s,2)
                  return
                concat(upper-case($fl), $tail)
                   ),
                   ''
                  )

      "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and apply it on this XML document:

```
<t>under_lined_String</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
UnderLinedString
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I do not know XPath 2.0 but from now on for sure I am gonna learn something of it. However your solution is not exactly what I want as the first letter in the result string has to be lower case.

Comment: @Jagger It is edited and produces your result -- just with a single XPath expression :)

Comment: @Dimitre Yes, it looks very neat. I switched to your solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using a template, recursively calling itself to iterate through the characters in the string. This template should take a position parameter, starting at 1
and increasing for each call to the template. When '_' is found, transform next char to upper case using translate(1.0) or upper-case(2.0)

Comment: I created such a monster 21 lines of xml instead of 1. But importantly it works. :) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yea it's not very delicate, i would agree on that. I tend to include these hacks from some common XSLT file, so i don't have to see them.

Comment: With XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0 there is a more straightforward solution and it does not require recursion. So, probably it is more efficient, too. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered, here's my solution:

```
<xsl:template name="camel-case">
  <xsl:param name='value'/>
  <xsl:analyze-string regex="^(.)" select="$value">
    <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="upper-case(regex-group(1))"/></xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:analyze-string regex="[_-](.)" select=".">
        <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="upper-case(regex-group(1))"/></xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>          
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="camel-case">
  <xsl:with-param name='value' select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
```